# Book class in Java with Enum and a HashSet

Tags: java, oop

Need to create a book class with some features:name,author,price.The type of the book must be an enum and also i need to add some books using hashset.

```
public class Book {

    enum Type {
        Classic_Literature, THRILLER, Psychology, MANUAL, Self_Improvement;
    }
        String name;
        String author;
        double price;


    public Book(String name, String author, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.price = price;

      }

    public String get.name() {
   return name;

    }
}
```

```
public class Books extends Book {


    public Books(String name, String author, double price) {
        super(name, author, price);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<String> books = new HashSet<>();
        carti.add("Baltagul");                //classical literature
        carti.add("Morometii");               //classical literature
        carti.add("Dezvoltarea personalitatii");
        carti.add("Criminalul ABC");
        carti.add("In mintea ta");
        carti.add("Abecedar");
        carti.add("Assassin's Creed Revelations");
        carti.add("In mintea lui");
        carti.add("Culegere Mate");
        carti.add("Public Speaking");
    }
}
```

The books are in Romanian so don't mind them.

My problem is:
-How can I make a link so that I can print out all books from "Literatura clasica"(Classical Literature)?

I don't exactly know how to implement such a method.

Comment: I don't see `carti` defined anywhere in the code you've shown us. Also, where do you actually *use* the `Type` enum anywhere? In the code you show us, you just define it.

Comment: Hi,  The code you are showing is really confusing.  Where is "carti" defined?  Assuming you are going to create some sort of collection of the book, iterate through the collection and for each object, check the Type, which you do not actually seem to be storing as an property of the Book Class.  I would **really** recommend reading [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Comment: The code you show doesn't even compile.

Comment: My,bad. "carti" comes from "books".The code was in my language and I forgot to change all words.

Comment: A few more points: first, why is `books` a hashset of strings? Shouldn't it be a HashSet of `Book` objects? Also, why did you make the `Books` class extend `Book`? You never actually instantiate `Books`, and even if you did it doesn't add anything to `Book` anyway, so this is entirely redundant.

Comment: This was the request from the professor.

Comment: That it be a HashSet of strings? That requirement really doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well,I should add books by myself so,shouldn't be strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas to start improving your code.....

```
public class Book {

    enum Type {
        Classic_Literature, THRILLER, Psychology, MANUAL, Self_Improvement;
    }

    String name;
    String author;
    double price;
    Type type;

    public Book(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Book(String name, Type type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
        books.add(new Book("Baltagul", Book.Type.Classic_Literature));                //classical literature
        books.add(new Book("Morometii", Book.Type.Classic_Literature));               //classical literature
        books.add(new Book("Dezvoltarea personalitatii"));
        books.add(new Book("Criminalul ABC"));
        books.add(new Book("In mintea ta"));

        //here you retrieve the classical literature books

        Set<Book> classicBooks = books.stream()
                .filter(b -> b.type == Book.Type.Classic_Literature)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
```

Comment: Why even introduce streams for a beginner? It'll just confuse them.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica - totally agree.  That is NOT beginner code.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica why not ? It is so easy to use

Comment: We started OOP at uni and the professor gave us some exercises.Some of them are quite common but this one gave me headaches.Didn't know how to implement it.At first I thought I should make a constructor for book and enum in order to give the type like if(book.getType()==something) but I guess streams and lambda work better despite I didn't use them yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are some misconceptions on the code.

1. Have the item as book and not use it within main. 

So why was defined ?
Maybe this is required:

`//colection of books`

`HashSet<Book> books = new HashSet<>();`

2. Why `Books` should extends `Book` ?
No need here.
 Books is just a regular class where you do aggregation via `HashSet`

3.Basic `Book` instantiation.
Maybe it's needed: 

 `books.put(new Book("Poezii", "Eminescu", 123))`

.4.Where is the classification of book linked ?

Maybe altering the constructor:

`public Book(String name, String author, double price, BookType bookType)`
 and after do a proper instantiation

.5. Display the books within a classification.
 Just use a regular loop within collection and validate only for a certain `BookType` (eg: Classic_Literature)
...